# when i run my code it gives error code 400 but when i do hot refresh it shows data in console while getting data from api in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, api, dart

when i run my code it gives error code 400 but when i do hot refresh it shows data in console while getting data from api in flutter

it means API needs time to send data but my code is not waiting
I am using async await too but still

please help if u can

here i m trying to fetch data

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
    import 'package:weather_app/services/location.dart';
    import 'package:weather_app/utilities/constants.dart';




    class LoadingScreen extends StatefulWidget {
    @override
    _LoadingScreenState createState() => _LoadingScreenState();
    }

    class _LoadingScreenState extends State<LoadingScreen> {
    double latitude;
    double longitude;

    @override
    void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getLocation();
    }

     void getLocation() async {
     GettingLocation gettingLocation = GettingLocation();
     await gettingLocation.getCurrentPosition();
      lattitude = gettingLocation.latitude;
      longitude = gettingLocation.longitude;
      }

      void getData() async {
      http.Response response = await http.get(Uri.parse(
          'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=$lattitude&lon=$longitude&appid=$apiKey'));

      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        String data = response.body;
        print(data);
      } else {
        print(response.statusCode);
      }
    }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    getData();
    return Scaffold();
  }
}
```

This is location.dart

```
    import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';

    class GettingLocation {
    double latitude;
    double longitude;

     Future<void> getCurrentPosition() async {
     try {
      Position position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(
          desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.low);

      latitude = position.latitude;
      longitude = position.longitude;
      } catch (e) {
       print(e);
      }
    }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not that the API needs time to return data, the problem is the order in which asynchronous methods execute.

This is the order of execution for what you show:

```
initState -> build -> getData -> getLocation
```

So by the time getData executes, getLocation is not done executing, so latitude and longitude don't have the correct values. When you run `hot reload`, only `build` and `getData` execute again, so the code works.

The simplest way to fix this is to move the call to `getLocation` into `getData` directly, but this means the data will take longer to fetch because the `getLocation` will only start executing when you execute `getData`.

First, remove `getLocation` from `initState`, then, on `getData`

```
    void getData() async {
      await getLocation(); // <------ this line
      http.Response response = await http.get(Uri.parse(
          'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=$lattitude&lon=$longitude&appid=$apiKey'));

      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        String data = response.body;
        print(data);
      } else {
        print(response.statusCode);
      }
    }
```

It is also worth mentioning that both `getData` and `getLocation` have a return type of `void`, this can have unexpected consequences when dealing with async callbacks, I recommend you replace it with `Future<void>`

```
Future<void> getLocation() { ... }

Future<void> getData() { ... }
```

Finally, as I said this solution has the slight disadvantage that the call to `getLocation` is moved into later, in practice there shouldn't be any problem with this, because the difference in time should be minuscule, but still I made an example using `FutureBuilder` that will display the `getData` data:

```
    class LoadingScreen extends StatefulWidget {
    @override
    _LoadingScreenState createState() => _LoadingScreenState();
    }

    class _LoadingScreenState extends State<LoadingScreen> {
    double latitude;
    double longitude;

    late Future<void> _locationFuture;

    @override
    void initState() {
      super.initState();
      _locationFuture = getLocation();
    }

    Future<void> getLocation() async {
      GettingLocation gettingLocation = GettingLocation();
      await gettingLocation.getCurrentPosition();
      lattitude = gettingLocation.latitude;
      longitude = gettingLocation.longitude;
    }

    Future<String?> getData() async {
      await _locationFuture;
      http.Response response = await http.get(Uri.parse(
          'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=$lattitude&lon=$longitude&appid=$apiKey'));

      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        return response.body;
        print(data);
      } else {
        print(response.statusCode);
      }
    }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<String?>(
      future: getData(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) return Text(snapshot.data!);
        return CircularProgressIndicator();
      }
    );
  }
}
```